# Prove, that $xe^{-x^{2}}+ye^{-y^{2}}+ze^{-z^{2}}\leq\sqrt{\frac{9}{2e}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Please help me prove, that for all real $x,y,z$

$$xe^{-x^{2}}+ye^{-y^{2}}+ze^{-z^{2}}\leq\sqrt{\frac{9}{2e}}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** It  is three independent single-variable calculus problems. Do you know how to maximize $te^{-t^2}$?

Comment: Hm... need to use derivatives and calculate global maximum? I'll try

Comment: Derivative of $te^{-t^2}$ is $-2t^2e^{-t^2}+e^{-t^2}$. Set equal to $0$, solve. We get $t=1/\sqrt{2}$. So max is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-1/2}$. Multiply by $3$.

Comment: Thanks. I've solved this task :-)